# angular4 http get 405 error

Tags: java, angular, http, get

been facing this issue all day and its officially beyond me. Ive looked over google trying different interpretations of trying to work this but it keeps offering me the same issue.

I am trying to http get to an api that is outside my corporate network. Using Java I have accomplished this before on the same api using

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new 
InetSocketAddress("proxy.example.com", portnumber));

HttpURLConnection con =
            (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlstring).openConnection(proxy);
```

I am now trying to get to the same api (urlstring) from an angular4 application.

within the service class i have:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' ,
                           'Authorization': 'BASE64AUTHENTICATION',
                           'Accept': 'application/json' }); 

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http.get(urlstring, options ).map(res => res.json());
```

I just dont see anything like the Java Proxy that will allow me to wrap my get request with the corporate proxy server.

Currently I am getting 'Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405' evry time I try to access the api. It seems to let me through far enough when I dont try using authentication headers but it is needed for this.

Comment: The backend of the server you’re sending that request to isn’t configured to allow OPTIONS requests. That’s what the 405 is telling you. So you need to configure that backend to handle OPTIONS requests — to send back a 200 OK response with the right CORS response headers. The reason why it need to handle OPTIONS requests is that your browser (automatically on its own) sends a CORS preflight OPTIONS request before trying the  GET request from your code. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests

Comment: hey..were you able to figure out the equivalent of java way in angular? Need to pass InetSocketAddress in Angular http calls as in Java but all I see online is Url appending by websock

Answer (score 0):

You should check your browser proxy configuration as your angular 4 app is running on that.

Comment: I actually thought this was a great suggestion. I tried using the proxy server through browser settings but no change to repsonse sadly. what i have noticed is if i use the Chrome CORS plugin it bypasses the CORS complaint. It then sends me a proper response (401) when i dont send any headers/request options. but when i add the Authorization header it then reverts to the 405.....